# $E(X_n)\rightarrow E(X)\nRightarrow E(|X_n-X|)\rightarrow 0$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

If $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of random variables and $X$ be another random variable, then as far as I know $$E(X_n)\rightarrow E(X)\nRightarrow E(|X_n-X|)\rightarrow 0$$ **always**. 
But I am not getting an example. Can somone provide me one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_n$ be Rademacher-distributed, i.e. $P(X_n = 1) = P(X_n = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $X = 0$. Then clearly $E[X_n] = 0 \to 0 = E[X]$, but $E[|X_n - X|] = E[|X_n|] = E[1] = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, just pick two different measurable functions $Y$ and $X$ with the same integral and set $X_n=Y$. Then $E[X_n]\equiv E[Y]=E[X]$ but $E[\lvert X_n-X\rvert]\equiv E[\lvert Y-X\rvert]>0$.

Comment: Explicit examples would help me better. Can you, please?

Comment: Pick $X\sim \mathcal N(1,1)$ and $Y=(X-1)^2$.

Comment: Your answer is fine to me. But I have an extra doubt: First, Basically, $Y\sim \chi^2_{(1)}$ . So what distribution will $|Y-X|$ follow? Second , if we are to find the expectation without finding a disribution, we will come across a term like $X^2$. What distribution will $X^2$ follow? (I know $E(X^2)=2$ still just asking for information!)